# Number of subsets from a set of size $2n$ with no two elements differing by $n-1$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f_r(n)$ = #$\{S \subset [2n]$ , s.t. there are no $x, y \in S$ for which $x − y = r\}$.
$[2n]$ denotes the set of size $2n$

Is there a formula for $f_{n-1}(n)$?

For example,

$f_1(2) = 8$

since the possible subsets from the set of size $4$ $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are $\{\phi,1,2,3,4,[1,3],[1,4],[2,4]\}$

If I'm not wrong, $f_2(3)=25$

I've already figured $f_n(n)=3^n$ using bijection, but I don't know how to solve for $f_{n-1}(n)$. Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $n\ge3$. Partition $[2n]$ into two groups of three – $1,n,2n-1$ and $2,n+1,2n$ – and $n-3$ groups of two. Each pair where $x-y=n-1$ fits into exactly one such group.

There are $5$ subsets of each group of three such that there is no pair with $x-y=n-1$, and $3$ such subsets for each group of two. Hence for $n\ge3$, $f_{n-1}(n)=25\cdot3^{n-3}$.